# Vector of pvalues from a vector of tstatistics?

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a vector of tstats is matlab,

e.g.,

```
tstat = [1.96;1.96;1.96];
```

My degrees of freedom is 500

Is it possible to get a vector of p-values

i.e.

```
pval = [0.05;0.05;0.05]
```

Comment: I guess that the values in `tstat` are critical values of the Student's `t`-distribution. If so, you might look for the `tcdf` function. Note that `tstat` is a Matlab function and thus a bad choice for a variable name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate p-value for t-test in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617050/how-to-calculate-p-value-for-t-test-in-matlab)